# SQL usertype Issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have used a `SQL query` to define the roles of the users in the table. For Example:-

1 -- Super Admin

2 -- Admins

3 -- Users

In gridview I want to display the text as `Super Admin` , `Admins` but still i am getting as `0`, `1` and `2`.

Please help

Code:-

```
SELECT (
        CASE WHEN usertype =1 THEN 'Admin' 
              WHEN usertype=0 THEN 'Super Admin' 
              WHEN usertype=2 THEN 'User' END ) aS usertype 
FROM tbl_User
```

Gridview aspx code:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUser" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnDataBound="grdUser_DataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdUser_RowDeleting"
            OnPreRender="PreRenderGrid" runat="server" Width="100%"
            border="1" DataKeyNames="Id" PageSize="2"
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging"
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
            CssClass="pagi" OnRowCommand="grdUser_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="UserName" 
                         ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="UserType" 
                           ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>                    
            </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is data in your column int or something else?Query looks fine to me

Comment: @Mihai: I have given the column as `varchar`

Comment: Then use quotes for numbers, in mysql would work,sql server is more rigurous. `CASE WHEN usertype ='1'` What happens is that sql server doesnt find anything equaling a number and returns NULLs.Assuming sql server.Or better yet change your column to int

Comment: @Mihai: Ok let me change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Grid event `RowDatabound`, you have to handle this or Your SQL query will return RoleDescription along with the roleID, then bind this on Grid

For RowDataBound Event:-

```
protected void ctrlGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
  {
     //add three case like this
    if (dataBoundItem["usertype"].Text == "1")
     Label lblUserType = (dataBoundItem["UserType"].FindControl("lblUserType") as Label);
     lblUserType.Text = "Admin";

 }
```

**EDIT:-**

Based on your sql query, I must say that change your alias name and add single quotes

```
SELECT Id,username,email,usertype,active, 
CASE WHEN usertype ='1' THEN 'Admin' 
WHEN usertype='0' THEN 'Super Admin' 
WHEN usertype='2' THEN 'User' END ) AS usertypeDescription 
from tbl_User ORDER By Id DESC
```

and then change

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="usertypeDescription" HeaderText="UserType" 
                       ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="k-grid td"></HeaderStyle>
       <ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
 </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: OK..What needs to be added under that ?

Comment: So only I have to change the aspx or both ?

Comment: change sql query(take query from answer) and change aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68497/discussion-between-nadeem-and-piyush).